# Volume of the region enclosed between the two paraboloids:

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

If we have two paraboloids, the first being  $z_1 = ax^2 + by^2$ and $z_2 = 6 − cx^2 − dy^2$, how does one show that the volume of the region enclosed by the two surfaces is $$\frac{18π}{\sqrt{(a + c)(b + d)}}$$

I tried finding the intersection first of all, where I would get $x^2(a+c) + y^2(b+d)$ = 6. If I switch my coordinates by using $ x' = x/\sqrt{a+c}$ and  $ y' = y/\sqrt{b+d}$, then I simply get that the region will be $x'^2+y'^2=6$. And, if I evaluate the jacobian - I get $\sqrt{(a + c)(b + d)}$.

But now evaluating the actual volume integral becomes the tricky part, if I try to evaluate each section individually - it becomes way too complicated. However, if I try to calculate the volume integral of ($z_2-z_1$) in cylindrical coordinates (while remaining in my new coordinates), I get the answer by integrating between $0<r'<\sqrt{6}$ and $0<\theta<2\pi$ - but I'm not exactly sure as to why. Surely this doesn't give the volume enclosed - but the volume that's missing? Any thoughts?

Comment: It does give the volume enclosed. You are bound below by $z_1$ and bound above by $z_2$. So integrating $(z_2-z_1)$ over $x^2(a+c) + y^2(b+d) \leq 6$ will give the bound volume which is after transformation, $0 \leq r \leq \sqrt6$.